# Using npm how can I download a package as a zip with all of its dependencies included in the package

Tags: node.js, package, npm

What I'm trying to do is download packages with all their dependencies, in order to transfer them to another computer that does not have an internet connection and install it there.

So the scenario would be:

1. Download package (to zip/tarball/whatever file) without installing it.
2. Included in that downloaded file would be all of its dependencies (correct versions, and it's dependencies' dependencies).
3. Transfer file to other computer.
4. Run `npm install` to file location (optional `-g` important).
5. Package is installed with dependencies.
6. Happy camper.

I feel like there has to be a npm command to download and pack (create) files this way.

I've tried looking for a solution for this to no avail.

This is my first time using node so I'm affraid I'm not researching it correctly because lack of knowledge of the node/npm lingo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just used [this gist by Jack Gill](https://gist.github.com/jackgill/7687308) to do exactly what you describe -- bundle up a package, *with* all its dependencies. Basically what the script does is re-write a module's `package.json` file to move all its `dependencies` to `bundleDependencies`, then pack the whole thing. Upload the resulting tarball to your server, then `npm install` it. Works a treat.

Comment: Kind of annoying that this functionality hasn't yet been added to npm without resorting to hacks.

Answer (score 9):

You can just use the `npm pack` command.

So for example:

```
npm pack lodash
```

This command will download the npm package and create a file `lodash-4.17.4.tgz`.

Installing this can be done with:

```
npm install ../../my-location/lodash-4.17.4.tgz
```

More details here:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-pack

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the package to a machine with internet.
2. Make sure your app package has a `package.json` file at its root with all of your dependencies listed in it. You can make npm save your dependencies in `package.json` by doing `npm install dependency-name --save`. The `--save` flag will cause npm to write the dependency to your app's `package.json` file if it has one. If it doesn't have on then it will do nothing. You can also instruct npm to create a `package.json` file for your app if you need to by simply running `npm init` from in your app's directory.
3. Run `npm install` from inside the app's directory. This will create the `node_modules` directory and install all the dependencies listed in the app's `package.json` file.
4. Zip up the directory now that it has a `node_modules` directory in it with all your dependencies installed. Transfer the zip archive to another machine.
5. Simply unpack the archive in its final destination and you're done. The app is now where it needs to be and the dependencies are already installed.
6. Now just run the application with `node app.js`, replacing "app.js" with whatever the name of the app's main entry point file is.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `npm install` in the package directory and archive the entirety of it.

Assuming there are no non-npm requirements you need to meet and both machines are running the same version of node, nothing more needs to be done. All of the downloaded dependencies will be installed inside the `./node_modules`. But it is a generally good idea to archive the entire package, as the developer might have implemented some additional setup routines.

Comment: What if the package is needed as a global (i.e. grunt)? I tried `npm i -g` in the package directory of the new machine.

Comment: @l__flex__l 
Global npm packages are hardly ever required. You can install them locally and run with, for example, `./node_modules/.bin/grunt`

Comment: How am I supposed to check that this package has no malicious install hook? There are reason why someone might want to download package as zip.

Answer (score 0):

you can download package with all its dependencies with its dependents using single command. Kindly refer this link [npm-package-downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-package-downloader)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30682113)

Comment: This is a bad repos. It suited only for windows (on linux/mac it crates backslashes in folders instead of slashes) and it doesn't include an integrity file.