# Automatically downloading npm packages listed in package.json file

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I'm working on creating a local repository that will contain all packages I use in my project, so I can have those packages installed on a machine that does not have access to the internet. I think of the repository that I could clone on the machine and run `yarn install` to have all the packages available in the project from the local repository. How can I do that? Similar question was asked here [Using npm how can I download a package as a zip with all of its dependencies included in the package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29767938/17422780)

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Updated the question, thanks @CarlMarkham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information in your question to fully understand your situation, but if you commit your `node_modules` directory to the repository, the modules will be there without the user having to run `npm` or `yarn` to install them. This assumes the user will run code from the repo workspace and that there aren't any modules that require a compilation step or other build step that may be platform-specific. But if they're all plain ol' JavaScript modules, you should be fine.

If you want to have all the modules as a separate repo rather than checking in `node_modules`, I can offhand think of two ways this might work.

1. Have the packages repo be a check-in of a fully installed `node_modules` directory. Then make that repo a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) of the main repo that gets cloned as `node_modules` in the main repo.
2. Use `npm pack` to create .tgz files for each package you need. Store those files in the packages repo. Clone that repo into a known path on your target machine. Have the main repo install via path names. For example, if you run `npm install /var/packages/foo-1.0.0.tgz`, it will add a line to your `package.json` that might look something like this: `"foo": "file:../../../var/packages/foo-1.0.0.tgz"`. In that case, `npm install` will install from that path rather than over the network.

Comment: that's exactly what I don't want to do. I want to have packages available in the local repository (I can download packages from git repo manually, but that's inefficient) and then just call ```yarn install``` , so the command will create node_modules folder with the packages listed in package.json file.

Comment: You want to have packages available in the local repository but having them checked in as part of the local repository is exactly what you don't want to do? I'm sorry, you're going to have to clarify.

Comment: OK , I see the confusion. I want to have two separate repositories, one with the main project, the other one will contain packages used in the main project. The reason for that is I don't want to mess up the main project. And to clarify the question further, how can I download all the packages listed in packages.json file, so those can be consumed by yarn to create the node_modules folder under the main project?

Comment: So the second repo (the one that contains all the packages) would be (or could be) a git submodule of the main repo? Or could be cloned elsewhere on the same machine? Like, either of those might work for you?

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional options that may meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the procedure I was looking for.